# How to prevent a "teardown" of my apk

Tags: android, encryption, proguard

According to this [link](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/11/apk-teardown-the-play-store-is-getting-a-built-in-malware-scanner-theres-more-wish-list-progress-and-more/), "Android Police" were able to teardown the Google Play apk and clearly read the strings file. I thought there were ways to prevent this using [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html), but does it work well? I remember watching the I/O conference this year and they mentioned something about encrypting your app I believe. I haven't read anything that has cured my anxiety about sending out an app that can not be decompiled/deconstructed or anything. Can anyone with experience vouch for this (proguard and this encryption thing)?

Comment: If your device can run the apk, then it must necessarily be possible to look inside the apk without running it, too. Stuff like proguard just makes it harder, not impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought there were ways to prevent this using proguard, but does it work well?

ProGuard obfuscates code. It does not do anything with resource files. It does not even encrypt string constants in code.

[DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard), a commercial offshoot of ProGuard, appears to encrypt string constants, though I see nothing about resources.

Moreover, none of this will help much. As Mr. Hewgill points out in a comment, by definition, everything has to be visible to run.

Answer (score 1):

Proguard obfuscates code, not resources. That said, even with obfuscation, once the app reads the string into memory, it's in cleartext. All that an attacker would need is a debugger and a breakpoint at just the right time.