# App encryption in Android Jelly Bean

Tags: android, encryption

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuC0i4xTyrI

Go to 34:55. I've been searching for this, and I even started a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866881/how-to-prevent-a-teardown-of-my-apk) about it, but I'm really still not sure what App encryption does. Anyone care to explain? Or has anyone used this?

Answer (score 1):

A very good overview is available at [Android Explorations](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-app-encryption-in-jelly-bean.html). The simplest way to describe it is that each app gets its own encrypted filesystem (think TrueCrypt) which is decrypted at runtime. The base key is stored in `/data/misc/systemkeys/AppsOnSD.sks`, and each device gets its own. When an app is loaded off of Play, a new partition is created and encrypted with that key before anything's written to disk, so no remnants are ever insecurely left around.

All parts of the app's base data are installed, both the apk and resources, except for whatever you choose to put in places like the Documents, cache dir, and other open areas.

Comment: bonus points for linking to Android Explorations. Excellent blog.